# Autogenerate a Django username with django-registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm trying to provide a user registration form without requiring a username to be manually entered.  I setup an authentication backend so that users can authenticate with an email address and that works because I can login with the Django admin user.  The idea is that my app would create a SHA1 hash of the email address to be stored as the Django username and the user would never see this.

I removed the username field from my registration html template, but I'm not sure how or where I should be generating the username programmatically. I think it should be in the clean_username method of the RegistrationForm, but that method doesn't get called when I use a template without the username field.

Any help would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: create user name where you are validating form in your view?

Comment: I would have to modify the django-registration view because I'm not writing the view.  How would I set the username though.  I can generate the hash of the email, but not sure what I would do with the hash.

Comment: one possible way is that do not do anything with django-registration, just hide the user name field on template, when user submit the form call javascript function before submitting and generate the username and set its value in post, one idea to generate username is to take the left hand side part of email and make changes.

Comment: @Aamir, I figured out a good way to handle this.  Check out my answer.  Thanks for the suggestions btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work.  I don't feel good about having to modify the registration's view method and the default registration backend directly.  I'd prefer to have those changes in my own code and am still working to make those changes, but this does indeed work.

Here's how I did it:

1. Created a custom registration backend called RegBackend that generates a sha1 hash based on the email address and then stores the hexdigest as the username, finally returning a User object.
2. Map register in urls.py to the new RegBackend that I created in step 1
3. Modified the django-registration's view register method to create a random username so that the form validates, but I never persist the random username.  I copied the request.POST dictionary and set this random username to one of the copy's dictionary keys called data['username'].  Then I use the data variable when creating an instance of the form_class.  Calling is_valid() on the form would return false because I removed the username from the template, but Django requires a username for registration, so I needed to supply it *something*.

I didn't use the sha1 hash for the random username because the Django username can only be 30 characters in length while the sha1 hash is 40.  Oddly, the custom registration backend didn't complain and can store the sha1 hash, but the form would generate errors because of the length when submitted.

**_*init*_.py** (I copied the existing DefaultBackend and modified with the SHA1 portion)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.sites.models import RequestSite
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

from registration import signals
from registration.forms import RegistrationForm
from registration.models import RegistrationProfile

import hashlib

class RegBackend(object):

def register(self, request, **kwargs):

hash_user = hashlib.sha1()
hash_user.update(kwargs['email'])

    username, email, password = hash_user.hexdigest(), kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']

    if Site._meta.installed:
        site = Site.objects.get_current()
    else:
        site = RequestSite(request)
    new_user = RegistrationProfile.objects.create_inactive_user(username, email,
                                                                password, site)
    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user

    #omitted other code from DefaultBackend that I didn't modify
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^register/$', register, {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.RegBackend', 'form_class': UserRegistrationForm}, name='registration_register'),
```

**registration/views.py**

```
def register(request, backend, success_url=None, form_class=None,
             disallowed_url='registration_disallowed',
             template_name='registration/registration_form.html',
             extra_context=None):

    backend = get_backend(backend)
    if not backend.registration_allowed(request):
        return redirect(disallowed_url)
    if form_class is None:
        form_class = backend.get_form_class(request)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # I added the next two lines
        data = request.POST.copy()
        data['username'] = ''.join([choice(letters) for i in xrange(30)])
        form = form_class(data=data, files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = backend.register(request, **form.cleaned_data)
            if success_url is None:
                to, args, kwargs = backend.post_registration_redirect(request, new_user)
                return redirect(to, *args, **kwargs)
            else:
                return redirect(success_url)

    else:
        form = form_class()

    if extra_context is None:
        extra_context = {}
    context = RequestContext(request)
    for key, value in extra_context.items():
        context[key] = callable(value) and value() or value

    return render_to_response(template_name,
                              {'form': form},
                              context_instance=context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be thinking of subclassing `RegistrationForm` and then overriding the `clean` method (I don't like that though, since the clean method has a clear purpose, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-clean-method)

A simpler solution might be to prompt the user to enter their email address, then process that form to generate your username, and pass that value to the `register` view as an extra context . Then instead of removing the username field, assign the hashed value to it and hide it in your template. That way, you won't have to mess around with django-registration itself.

See https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/src/fad7080fe769/registration/views.py for more info on the `extra_context` argument.